# IO inside the Get Monad

Tags: haskell, redis, binaryfiles

So my problem is as follows. I'm trying to implement a streaming parser for RDB files (the dump files that Redis produces). I want to implement a function similar to mapM_ whereby I can , say print out each object represented in the dump file as it is parsed. However, I can't seem to get it to operate in constant space. I find that what is happening is that I'm building a large IO() thunk inside of the Get monad, returning from the Get monad and then executing the IO. Is there anyway to stream my objects as they are parsed to print and then discard them? I've tried Enumerators and Conduits but I haven't seen any real gain. Here is what I have so far:

```
loadObjs_ :: (Monad m) => (Maybe Integer -> BL8.ByteString -> RDBObj -> Get (m a)) -> Get (m a)
loadObjs_ f = do
             code <- lookAhead getWord8
             case code of
                0xfd -> do
                 skip 1
                 expire <- loadTime
                 getPairs_ f (Just expire)
               0xfc -> do
                 skip 1
                 expire <- loadTimeMs
                 getPairs_ f (Just expire)
               0xfe -> f Nothing "Switching Database" RDBNull
               0xff -> f Nothing "" RDBNull
               _ -> getPairs_ f Nothing

getPairs_ :: (Monad m) => (Maybe Integer -> BL8.ByteString -> RDBObj -> Get (m a)) -> Maybe Integer -> Get (m a)
getPairs_ f ex = do
                !t <- getWord8
                !key <- loadStringObj False
                !obj <- loadObj t
                !rest <- loadObjs_ f
                !out <- f ex key obj
                return (out >> rest)


(loadObj does the actual parsing of a single object but I believe that whatever I need to fix the streaming to operate in constant or near-constant memory is at a higher level in the iteration than loadObj)

getDBs_ :: (Monad m) => (Maybe Integer -> BL8.ByteString -> RDBObj -> Get (m a)) -> Get (m a)
getDBs_ f = do
           opc <- lookAhead getWord8
           if opc == opcodeSelectdb
              then do
                  skip 1
                  (isEncType,dbnum) <- loadLen
                  objs <- loadObjs_ f
                  rest <- getDBs_ f
                  return (objs >> rest)
              else f Nothing "EOF" RDBNull

processRDB_ :: (Monad m) => (Maybe Integer -> BL8.ByteString -> RDBObj -> Get (m a)) -> Get (m a)
processRDB_ f = do
                header <- getBytes 9
                dbs <- getDBs_ f
                eof <- getWord8
                return (dbs)

printRDBObj :: Maybe Integer -> BL8.ByteString -> RDBObj -> Get (IO ())
printRDBObj (Just exp) key obj = return $ (print ("Expires: " ++ show exp) >>
                                           print ("Key: " ++ (BL8.unpack key)) >> 
                                           print ("Obj: " ++ show obj))
printRDBObj Nothing key RDBNull = return $ (print $ BL8.unpack key)
printRDBObj Nothing key obj = return $ (print ("Key: " ++ (BL8.unpack key)) >> 
                                        print ("Obj: " ++ show obj))


main = do
       testf <- BL8.readFile "./dump.rdb"
       runGet (processRDB_ printRDBObj)  testf
```

Thanks all in advance.

Best,
Erik

EDIT: Here is my attempt to parse the objects into a lazy list and then IO over the lazy list.

```
processRDB :: Get [RDBObj]

processRDB = do
                header <- getBytes 9
                dbs <- getDBs
                eof <- getWord8
                return (dbs)

main = do
       testf <- BL8.readFile "./dump.rdb"
       mapM_ (print . show) $ runGet processRDB testf
```

Comment: Have you tried http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-strict ?

Comment: I haven't tried binary-strict but I did try the strict getting of cereal to no avail.

Comment: You don't want to make it stricter, you want to make it lazier.  Something somewhere is being too strict. But I don't know my way around the relevant packages well enough.

Comment: @ErikHinton - can you please provide the code for `getDBs` in your lazy list attempt?  That's probably closer to doing what you want.  If you switch from binary to a monadic parser combinator library (parsec, and technically iteratee/enumerator are also) you could also have success with that approach.  I don't think it's possible to do this with a type of `Get (m a)` though.

Comment: Does the IO need interleaved with the parsing? I find that it's cleaner and (typically) faster to split the parsing and the processing into distinct halves.

Comment: @NathanHowell the IO doesn't have to be interleaved but I'm not having much success keeping the parsing in constant memory otherwise. Heck, I'm not having much success period. The closest I've come is https://gist.github.com/c3db0a27610d87a9a56e This works in constant space on certain dump files but, on others, suffers a few short, sharp spikes of 100MB+ allocations for ARR_WORDS that I can't seem to diagnose.

Comment: @NathanHowell I would love to know though if you had clean strategy for iterative parsing and IO that could just print each part of the dump out once the parser was satisfied.

Comment: @ErikHinton Any chance you could put up the full parser and a sample database dump somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your code correctly, you are trying to convert the file contents into IO actions incrementally, in the hope of then executing those actions incrementally.

A better approach would be to have your parser return a lazy list of objects which you then print out.

Comment: Ah yes, I have tried this as well. I have a version of the code that parses the RDB into a list of objects upon which I call `mapM_ . (print . show)` alas I see the same heap spike at the beginning of my execution which gradually dimishes as it iterates through and garbage collects: